# Delay of ripple carry adder

Tags: logic-gates, delay, adder, binary, ripple

[image: 4bit ripple carry adder]

I denote delay timing as "@ value". As you can see the picture above, C_in0(carry in 0), A0(input A's 0th bit), and B0 are initially ready so there is no delay which means they all have @0 delay. The rest of delays is also indicated on the picture.

My Question is why S0 is @2 not @1.
To my knowledge, the sum part in Full Adder has 2 levels that are xor both. Therefore if an incoming Cin's delay is n, the total delay of the part is n+1. For example, if you look at FA2 in the above picture you can see Cin1 is @2 so S1's delay is 3(2+1).In my example, Cin0 = 0 so the S0's delay should be 1. Maybe the picture below helps you understand what I am saying.
[image: The sum part in Full adder]

Comment: And what when the incoming A's delay is n? Then what is the total delay of the part?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
Let me be clear, If Cin's delay is n, and A and B's delay is 0 the total delay for the sum part in full gate is n+1.

Comment: what if n is less than 0? if A's delay is 0 and B's delay is 0 and Cin's delay is -3 does that mean the sum's delay is -2? No. Why not?

Comment: Oh I've never thought that delay can has minus value.
Anyway thank you for your comment.
First of all, I am considering the worst case only here for your information.
As you can see the second picture, inputs have no delay. I think it is obvious because inputs are always ready to get into the gate. On the other hand carry_in is not ready because delay has been rippled through the carry propagation. So if C_in has @n delay, at the first xor gate, it takes @1 and then it takes n+1 at the second xor gate.

Comment: @SeungHwanKwan I'm not sure what you mean but I think you are still ignoring A and B. Start thinking about A and B. If C_in's delay is 100 and A's delay is 200 and B's delay is 300 then what is S's delay? Is it 101? Or is it not 101?

Comment: In that case i think the delay is 302 (300 + 1 + 1) because the critical path occurs with B! :)

Comment: Is S ready at the exact same time B is ready? Or does B have to go through some gates first to calculate S? How many gates?

Comment: B go through two Xor gates. one with A and another with Cin

Comment: So at what time would S be ready, if B was ready at time 300?

Comment: i guess the previous comment helped you realize the answer.